# Is there a Rails Console command (Rails 3+) to reload changed code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am playing with the console, I change some model code and now I want to test it. I normally re-start the console. Is there a quicker way? Maybe a console command to reload the model code?

Comment: I had the same problem (reload! doesn't work like I need) writing a little helper code - so I ended up using [link] (http://codepad.org/) to test. Works nice.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Of course, simply type:

```
reload!
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. If I comment out a method in a model then type `reload!` the method still works after the reload. ?!? I wonder why and if there's another way to 're-start' the console?

Comment: @Meltemi: it's just the way Ruby works (concept of open classes): it rereads all definitions, overriding existing methods but doesn't flush old ones. Use `Class.send(:remove_method, :method_name)` to do the trick

Comment: Just to add 5 cents: if you'r using `Pry`, sometimes you need to add `self.send(:include, Rails::ConsoleMethods)`

Comment: This doesn't work for code manually required from `lib`. Any way to reload that code?

Comment: Rails continues to delight!

Answer (score 10):

You need to call `reload!`

This command will clear the loaded constants that have been loaded and will load them as they're referenced in the console.

If you have old objects from before the `reload!` you will need to call `reload` on these individual objects or find new objects and work with them if you want to try out the new method.

Answer (score 1):

You can type `reload!`.

I think it's important to note that `reload!` doesn't reinitialize rails console session existing objects, it just reloads the code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10465369/9185715
So, if you have instantiated any objects in the console, they won't be reinitialized.