# how do I reload a model in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
> rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]

> rails -v
Rails 3.1.1
```

Related, but didn't answer: [Is there a Rails Console command (Rails 3+) to reload changed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602897/is-there-a-rails-console-command-rails-3-to-reload-changed-code)

I'm using the Rails console to try and figure out why a method in my model isn't being called. The model is in ./app/models/product.rb. I'm changing a method from being called as `self.trim_history` to `trim_history`. I'm still wrapping my head around when to call a method as `self.do_stuff` or just `do_stuff`.

Well in the course of figuring this out I've run into a problem with `reload!`. My understanding was that `reload!` would load all the models and controllers again, but that doesn't seem to be working. When I debug my code, the line that I've changed to be `do_stuff` is still showing as `self.do_stuff` in the debugger.

I've attempted to solve this with `reload!`, no fix. I've reloaded the object from the database after reloading, no fix. I've loaded the model directly with `load './app/models/product.rb'`, then loaded the object from the db, no fix. I've verified that the object is being changed with `tail`.

What's the best way to reload a model in the rails console? Do I have to re-start the console every time my model code changes? Is there some way to just dump all of the existing models and their code without reloading the console?

**Edit**: this got stranger. I now suspect that my code is being reloaded but the debugger is not reflecting the new code. When I step through the code, the old code is there, but the new code is being executed. I tested this by adding a `raise` -- the `raise` never shows in the debugger but it is raised. Wat?

Is there something I need to do with the debugger to get it to see the reloaded code? This looks like a bug...

Comment: Are you trying to call the method on the class itself or an instance of the class?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz instance of the class; I'm reading about using self and messing with the code until I understand it.

Comment: There are several different debuggers for Ruby, it'd be helpful to specify which one you're using.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall my gemfile has   `ruby-debug-base19x` and `ruby-debug19` -- I was running into issues with the debugger and linecache recently so they are probably both in there because of that...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`reload!` doesn't reinitialize existing objects, it just reloads the code. If you create a new instance of the class it should reflect the changes.

Comment: this is covered in the OP, perhaps I'm not creating the object in the way you are thinking? I'm creating it by loading it from the db: `p = Product.by_name 'Acme Mop'` -- this is calling `Product.where(name: name).first` -- could that be the issue?

Comment: @jcollum He's not saying that *how* they're created is relevant, but rather *when*. Are you creating the objects before or after you call `reload!`?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall again, covered in the OP. I am loading the object from the db after calling `reload!` and the code changes are not being reflected in the object

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I'm thinking this may be an issue with the debugger -- see my edit.

Comment: @jcollum Great question! Coded Ruby for > 10 yrs and I've never really thought this issue through. Normally, in your example, I'd try reload! and instance.reload on my object and it'd seem that sometimes it'd work, others not. Then I'd restart my console and that would always work. So I just tried to figure it out and Chris is right. If you're work with an instance of a Class, then reloading does reload everything EXCEPT the instance (which makes sense). So if you instantiate after reloading, then it'd have the new code. Thanks. Now I won't needlessly enter reload..